# Updating row values with numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following function:

```
def invert_blackwhite(x):

for riga in x:

    for idx_colonna in range(len(riga)):

        if (riga[idx_colonna] == 0):

            riga[idx_colonna] = 1

        else:

            riga[idx_colonna] = 0            
    print(riga)
return x
```

If I call this function like this:

```
x = np.array([[0,1,0],[1,1,1],[0,1,0],[0,1,0]])
invert_blackwhite(x)
```

The output would be this:

```
[1 0 1]
[0 0 0]
[1 0 1]
[1 0 1]
```

In the function, I am iterating over rows and changing the content of the rows based on a condition. I am not really sure why the code is also updating the variable "x" since I am just calling the riga object. To summarize, I can not understand why if I update the riga object that automatically updates also x. I hope that my doubt is clear

Comment: You can use `np.logical_not`, `x = np.logical_not(x).astype(np.uint8)`

Comment: a mandatory link to [Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) Facts and myths about Python names and values

Comment: you create x , you send it to a function, you modify x, then you return it ... read the above link to understand why that happens, an obvious solution if you don't want to modify x is to send a  copy of it to the function.

Comment: `riga` is a row of `x`, a 2d array.  In `numpy` such an array is a `view`.  Have you read enough of the basic `numpy` docs to learn the difference between `view` and `copy`?